# How to compile multiple stored procedures from a single file?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

With `.sql`, you can run queries from multiple `.sql` files using language like this: `@query.sql`

How can you do the same with Oracle? I'd like to compile 5 stored procedures from 5 different files using a sixth file to source the 5 procedures.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add further explanation.  The way I'm reading this it sounds like you have five procedures in five separate files - OK - and then "a sixth file to source the 5 procedures".  I'm not parsing this properly - what does the sixth file provide?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@/path/main_script.sql:
START script_one.sql
START script_two.sql
START script_three.sql
START script_four.sql
START script_five.sql
```

OR

```
@/path/main_script.sql:
@@/path/script_one.sql
@@/path/script_two.sql
@@/path/script_three.sql
@@/path/script_four.sql
@@/path/script_five.sql
```